# Python Pandas Dataframe filter not working

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a Pandas dataframe called df with the following content:

```
    Symbol                     Cat         Beta Eps MktCap
2350    FBP  Foreign Regional Banks            0   0      0
2351   FNBC  Foreign Regional Banks            0   0      0
2353   BSBR  Foreign Regional Banks            0   0      0
2354    BBD  Foreign Regional Banks            0   0      0
2355    HDB  Foreign Regional Banks            0   0      0
2356    BCH  Foreign Regional Banks            0   0      0
2358     WF  Foreign Regional Banks            0   0   None
2359   SMFG  Foreign Regional Banks            0   0   None
2360    BFR  Foreign Regional Banks            0   0      0
2361    BCA  Foreign Regional Banks            0   0      0
2362   BPOP  Foreign Regional Banks            0   0   None
2363    CIB  Foreign Regional Banks            0   0      0
2364   ITUB  Foreign Regional Banks            0   0      0
2365    BMA  Foreign Regional Banks            0   0      0
2366     KB  Foreign Regional Banks            0   0   None
2367   BBDO  Foreign Regional Banks            0   0      0
2368   BSMX  Foreign Regional Banks            0   0   None
2369   BBVA  Foreign Regional Banks            0   0   None
2370    SHG  Foreign Regional Banks            0   0      0
2352     DB  Foreign Regional Banks         1.08   0      0
2357    MFG  Foreign Regional Banks  6.101694915   0   None
```

I use the following Python code:

```
df2 = df[df.Beta > 0]
```

The resulting df2 does not filter out the 0 values for Beta meaning it stays equal to df. How do I fix this?
Thanks

Comment: It does work for me. What's the data type of `Beta`? When I read your dataframe using `read_clipboard()` the column gets assigned `float` format and it just works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you can try cast to `float` by [`astype`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.astype.html) - it seems `dtype` of column `Beta` is `object` (then `type` is obviously `string`):

```
df2 = df[df.Beta.astype(float) > 0]
```

Comment: I would probably cast to int - compared floats will be iffy at best.Especially if some values are close to zero or are the result of computations

Comment: @ChristianSauer - and if change condition with `=>` or `=<` then get incorrect output - because `print (int(6.9))` return `6`.

Comment: @BryanDowning - Glad can help you!

Comment: @jezrael Rounding problems are the reason for my suggestion. Alternatively, you coud use a function which takes tie acceptable difference into account, numpy.isclose if I recall correctly

Comment: @BryanDowning  Sure, but I think numpy.isclose is better for compare with float scalar values, or not? I think cast to int can return wrong output - `df[df.Beta.astype(int) == 1]` return row with `Beta` = `1.08`. Can you explain more?

Comment: @jezreal I am use float not casting to int

Comment: @BryanDowning - It is correct. I try explain why is not good idea cast to int.

Answer (score 0):

I have a pandas df that looks like this: [pandas df](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WcUQy.png).

My issue is that when I try to find a certain state using a filter or conditionals, I get that the state doesn't exist, even though I can see it does.

Ex.

```
state_df.loc[state_df['state'] == 'AK']
```

results in a df with no rows, meaning it cannot find AK.

I think the issue may be related to the dtype of the columns, but it also looks fine to me:

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 44 entries, 0 to 43
Data columns (total 6 columns):
state                     44 non-null object
high_risk_per_ICU_bed     44 non-null float64
high_risk_per_hospital    44 non-null float64
icu_beds                  44 non-null float64
hospitals                 44 non-null float64
total_at_risk             44 non-null float64
dtypes: float64(5), object(1)
memory usage: 2.2+ KB
```

If it helps, I created the column `state` by using a `groupby` function and aggregating with `sum`, though I don't think that would cause this error.